# sending data from controller to view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller, view

I have controller that loads a customer details view which includes the name of the customer, email, fax,phoneNo. ...etc i want the user of the system when types in the form of the customer name to check if this customer exists in the database and instantly to show his contact details in the forms of email, fax , ...etc
is this doable without having to load the view once again ?

Comment: Are you lookin for [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)?
You can see customer details while searching their names. Here is how to do it in CI. [tutorial](http://www.jamipietila.fi/codeigniter-and-autocomplete-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can do this by having a array of customers when you loading the view, when user types the name you can check this value with array you have. It is to be noted you have to make js array of the php array you get from the controller.

2.Use ajax. Simple and dynamic.

Comment: do you mean using ajax to send the data array from the controller to the view ? can you guide me into how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

**Controller: [I am writing only the functions.]**

```
public function customer_details() {
       $data['base_url'] = base_url();
       $data['somedata'] = 'somevalue';
       $this->load->view('customerDetailsView',$data);
}
public function ajax_fetchDetails() {
       $customerName = $this->input->post('cname');
       $this->load->model('customerDetails');
       $cdetails = $this->customerDetails->fetchdetails($customerName);
       if(!empty($cdetails)) {
          echo json_encode($cdetails);
       }
       else echo '0'; //Handle it in view.
}
```

---

**Model: [Write your own Query]**

```
Select * from `customerdetails` where `name` like $customerName limit = 1;
```

---

**View: customerDetailsView [I am writing only what should appear in the  tag]**

```
<label for='cname'>Customer Name:</label> <input type="text" id="cname" />
<br/>
<input type="button" id="fetchbtn" value="Fetch Details" />
<br/>
<label for='email'>Email: </label> <input type="text" id="email" />
<label for='fax'>Fax: </label> <input type="text" id="fax" />
```

... So on Untill all the details are covered.

```
<!--For the following script to work you'll have to use jquery library.-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fetchbtn").onclick( function(event) {
        var name = jQuery.trim($("#cname").val()); //Fetch the customer name enter in the input field.
        if(name != '') // Check for empty condition
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url:"<?php echo $base_url.'<CONTROLLER NAME>/ajax_fetchDetails'; ?>",
            data:{cname:name},
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result != '0') {
                        var customerDetails = JSON && JSON.parse(result) || $.parseJSON(result); // Parse the JSON encoded customer details into string.
                        var email = customerDetails.email, fax = customerDetails.fax; //... So on
                        $("#email").val(email); $("#fax").val(fax); //... So on
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
  </script>
```

The only disadvantage here is, if two customers have same name only the 1st customer's details will be fetched. To avoid this, you'll have to maintain unique username for each customer.